# Redundant quotation mark during template literal and map to dynami object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
mongooseFilters = sort.items.map(i => ({[`'${i.field}'`] : i.sortOption == SortOption.ASC ? 1 : -1}))
```

My **expectation** was:

```
[ { 'name': 1 }, { 'surname': -1 }, { 'customerType': -1 } ]
```

Reality **is**

```
[ { "'name'": 1 }, { "'surname'": -1 }, { "'customerType'": -1 } ]
```

**So, why i have the extra "" in the result?**

Finally I would like to have something like this:

```
{ 'name': 1, 'surname': -1, 'customerType': -1 }
```

So I can use reduce

```
const result = mongooseFilters.reduce((a,v) => ({...a, ...v}))
```

This works, but yes - with the extra **"**

```
{ "'name'": 1, "'surname'": -1, "'customerType'": -1 }
```

Comment: The quotes inside the template literal are being processed literally.

Comment: What did you think `\`'${i.field}'\`` indicated?

Comment: Two options, JSON does not like single quotes as qualifiers, so change the single quote to  a proper double quote. Secondly, as you are creating this dynamically, remove the single quote from the literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put quotes inside the template literal. The template literal already returns a string, you don't need additional quotes to make a string. Those quotes are being added literally to the keys.

You don't even need the template literals, just use `i.field`.

```
mongooseFilters = sort.items.map(i => ({[i.field] : i.sortOption == SortOption.ASC ? 1 : -1}))
```

And if you want the final result as a single object, don't create an array of objects. Return a 2-dimensional array and use `Object.fromEntries()`.

```
mongooseFilters = Object.fromEntries(sort.items.map(i => [i.field, i.sortOption == SortOption.ASC ? 1 : -1]));
```

Comment: Do you mean that i don't need the quotation in the result at the key's position? According to this description https://www.statology.org/mongodb-sort-by-multiple-fields/ i shoud use the "" when I want to sort by multiple fileds in the mongoose. Your solution returns { name: -1, surname: 1, customerType: -1 }

Comment: Quotes are used in literals, not in the data itself.